# Como alterar parametros de uma classe dentro de uma thread

Tags: python, thread

Eu estou inicializando uma classe no escopo global, depois eu crio uma thread que altera um parametro desta classe. Apos encerrar a thread eu pergunto a classe qual o valor do parametro que acabo de alterar, ela me diz que ele nada foi alterado.

Por que e como resolver isso?

Meu codigo:

```
import multiprocessing 
import time

class Car:

    color = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.color = "green"

    def changeColor(self, color):
        self.color = color

    def getColor(self):
        return self.color

car1 = Car()

def carshop():
    car1.changeColor("red")
    print(car1.getColor())

th = multiprocessing.Process(target = carshop, args=())
th.start()

time.sleep(2)

print(car1.getColor())
```

Retorno deste codigo:

```
red
green
```

como deveria ser o retorno deste codigo:

```
red 
red
```

Comment: também não faz sentido usar getters e setters em Python do jeito que está fazendo. Justamente por estar fazendo isso num ambiente multi-threading, vocẽ pode querer escrever getters e setters que usem um Lock para evitar race-conditions - mas nesse caso, em Python, use um `@property` - não código desse jeito aí.

Comment: e não comentei sobre a pergunta, por que a resposta existente está correta: você esta usando multiprocessing: é diferente de threading. Se o código acima fosse com threads, o objeto `car1` teria sido alterado, e o mesmo objéto é visível em todas as threads. Com multi-processing, quando o  processo worker é criado, todas as variáveis do processo atual são clonadas no processo novo, e tem vida independente a partir daí - só comunicação inter-processo explícita (por exemplo, com uma multiprocessing.Queue), para passar dados de um lado para outro.

Comment: @jsbueno interessante seu ponto, de fato o código que mostrei é apenas exemplo para um problema maior que não seria interessante postar aqui, mas vou seguir sua fala. Eu não posso usar threads mas queria efetuar a atualização dessa variável no escopo global, poderia fazer isso com essa fila de comunicação?

Comment: sim - acho que vai ficar melhor em outra pergunta, com o titulo sobre multi-processing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está usando `multiprocessing`. A resposta mais curta e simples é que **processos não compartilham memória por padrão**. Tente usar `threading` ao invés disso.

```
import threading
import time

class Car:
    def __init__(self):
        self.color = "green"

    def changeColor(self, color):
        self.color = color

    def getColor(self):
        return self.color

car1 = Car()

def carshop():
    car1.changeColor("red")
    print(car1.getColor())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    th = threading.Thread(target=carshop)
    th.start()

    time.sleep(2)
    print(car1.getColor())
```

Comment: Existe alguma forma de forçar ele a compartilhar?